# Why pytest can't import tinydb module?

Tags: python, import, pytest

I'm working through the "Python Testing with Pytest" book.

I'm importing tinydb module to run assertions against it and terminal is giving
me error:

```
test_add_variety.py:1: in <module>                                                   
import pytest, tasks, tinydb                                                     
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinydb'
```

however it is installed:

`pip3 freeze`:

```
click==7.1.2                                                                         
six==1.16.0                                                                          
tasks==0.1.0                                                                         
tinydb==3.15.1
```

and I can also confirm by firing up Python interpreter:

```
(venv) mark@fid:~/p_test/ch2$ python                                                 
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42)                                       
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux                                                                 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.               
>>> import tinydb                                                                    
>>>
```

Please note that I'm running these with virtual environment activated.

Any suggestions why Pytest can't import `tinydb` module ?

Comment: On the off chance that the error is not actually tinydb, try imports one on each line as recommended by pep8. pip3 freeze does not show pytest.

Comment: As expected that made no difference but I do know it should've been on separate line.

Comment: It looks like Pytest had problem with `tinydb` because Pytest was installed globally and not within venv.

Comment: Is this necessary in the test module for some reason? from tinydb import TinyDB

Comment: Problem went away as soon as I uninstalled Pytest from the system and installed it into venv.